# Notifications in Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

So I tried to make notification

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(
    this, NavigationActivity.class
);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Message received")
    .setContentText("Message body")
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

And it doesn't appear. Just nothing happen, no error or something. The log is empty. Android 6.0. The icon resource is exists.

Is there a way to know for sure what is the problem? Where to look for the  error message?

Comment: Try with flag `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Do you have the LogCat output? Can you share it?

Comment: Tried different flags, icons, intents, even null. Log is empty. Just nothing there.

Comment: try to change the icon once. Give any system drawable

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NotificationCompat.Builder instead of Notification.Builder. For more information look at [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification).

Comment: But I don't want a compat :) I don't want my app to carry all that junk from old versions. Just hate a whole concept of a backward compat. (Actually, I had tried it, and it doesn't work either)

Comment: Then check that your phone settings don't forbid notifications, go to Settings->Apps->Your App->Notifications and make sure that "Block all" not checked. Sorry maybe this recommendation seems to be stupid but I must try :)

Comment: Yep, exactly, it is :D

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm sooooo idiot. I had the system settings switch on, that blocks all the notifications for the app. Sorry for that.